Why is the entropy change for a system in irreversible transformations the same as in reversible transformations in some cases, not in other cases?
Generally, the entropy change for a closed system for an irreversible transformation is not the same in a closed system for a reversible transformation.
A clear counterexample is that of an adiabatic transformation.
1.1) Change in entropy in adiabatic reversible transformation for a closed system.
Since $\Delta S = \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}}}{T}$ and $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = 0$ in a reversible adiabatic process, we have
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ adiabatic}} = 0$$
1.2) Change in entropy in adiabatic irreversible transformation for a closed system.
We can't take an irreversible adiabatic process and evaluate the change in entropy. We have to ideate a reversible path between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium initial ($I$) and final ($F$) states which need not be the same path as the reversible one (actually, in this case, doing so would be invalid).
We can take this reversible path as the combination of an isochoric reversible process and an isothermal reversible process.

Isochoric reversible process between initial state $I$ and transition equilibrium midpoint state $M$. From the 1st Law of Thermodynamics $\delta Q = \mathrm{d}U + \delta W$, and since $\delta W = 0$ for an isochoric reversible process, we have $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = \mathrm{d}U = n c_V \mathrm{d}T$. 
So:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}} = \displaystyle \int \frac{\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}}}{T} = \displaystyle \int\limits_{T_I}^{T_M} \frac{nc_V \mathrm{d}T}{T} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_M}{T_I}\right)$$

Isothermal reversible process between transition equilibrium midpoint state $M$ and final state $F$. From the 1st Law of Thermodynamics $\delta Q = \mathrm{d}U + \delta W$, and since $\delta U = 0$ for an isothermal reversible process, we have $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = \delta W = p \mathrm{d}V = \dfrac{nRT}{V}\mathrm{d}V$. 
So:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = \displaystyle \int \frac{\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}}}{T} = \displaystyle \int\limits_{V_M}^{V_F} \frac{\frac{nRT}{V}\mathrm{d}V}{T} = n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_M}\right).$$


Finally:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ adiabatic}} = \Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}} + \Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_M}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_M}\right).$$ 
Since $T_M = T_F$ and $V_M = V_I$:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ adiabatic}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right)$$
So: $$\boxed{\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ adiabatic}} = 0 \neq \left[n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right)\right] = \Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ adiabatic}}}.$$
In other cases (isothermal, isochoric, isobaric), the entropy change for a closed system in the reversible case turns out to be exactly the same as the entropy change for a closed system in the irreversible case. Below are the calculations.
2.1) Change in entropy in isothermal reversible transformation for a closed system.
Since $\mathrm{d}U = 0$ and $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = \delta W = p \mathrm{d}V = \dfrac{nRT}{V} \mathrm{d}V$ in a reversible isothermal process, we have
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = \displaystyle \int\limits_{V_I}^{V_F} \frac{\frac{nRT}{V} \mathrm{d}V}{T} = nR \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right)$$
2.2) Change in entropy in isothermal irreversible transformation for a closed system.
We can't take a reversible isothermal process and evaluate the change in entropy. We have to ideate a reversible path between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium initial ($I$) and final ($F$) states which need not be the same path as the reversible one.
We can apply the same procedure in 1.2), as there is an infinite number of reversible transformations conducing from the initial to the final state, giving the same change in entropy. 
We have:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right),$$
and since $T_I = T_F$ in an isothermal process, we have
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right),$$
So: $$\boxed{\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}} = n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right) = \Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isothermal}}}.$$
3.1) Change in entropy in isobaric reversible transformation for a closed system.
Since $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = n c_P \mathrm{d}T$ in a reversible isobaric process, we have
$$\begin{align*}
\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isobaric}} &= \displaystyle \int\limits_{T_I}^{T_F} \frac{n c_P \mathrm{d}T}{T} \\
&= n c_P \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) \\
&= n (c_V + R) \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) \qquad \text{(since $c_P = c_V + R$ by Mayer's relation)} \\
&= n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) \\
&= n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{p_F V_F}{P_I V_I}\right) \qquad \text{(from $pV = nRT$ by Ideal Gas Law)} \\
&= n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right)\\
\end{align*}$$
3.2) Change in entropy in isobaric irreversible transformation for a closed system.
We can't take a reversible isobaric process and evaluate the change in entropy. We have to ideate a reversible path between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium initial ($I$) and final ($F$) states which need not be the same path as the reversible one.
We can apply the same procedure in 1.2) and 2.2), as there is an infinite number of reversible transformations conducing from the initial to the final state, giving the same change in entropy. 
We have:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isobaric}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right).$$
So: $$\boxed{\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isobaric}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right) = \Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isobaric}}}.$$

4.1) Change in entropy in isochoric reversible transformation for a closed system.
Since $\delta W = 0$ and $\delta Q_{\mathrm{reversible}} = \mathrm{d}U = n c_V \mathrm{d}T$ in a reversible isochoric process, we have
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}} = \displaystyle \int\limits_{T_I}^{T_F} \frac{n c_V \mathrm{d}T}{T} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right)$$
4.2) Change in entropy in isochoric irreversible transformation for a closed system.
We can't take a reversible isochoric process and evaluate the change in entropy. We have to ideate a reversible path between the same two thermodynamic equilibrium initial ($I$) and final ($F$) states which need not be the same path as the reversible one.
We can apply the same procedure in 1.2), 2.2) and 3.2), as there is an infinite number of reversible transformations conducing from the initial to the final state, giving the same change in entropy. 
We have:
$$\Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) + n R \ln \left(\frac{V_F}{V_I}\right),$$
and since $V_I = V_F$ in an isochoric process, we have
So: $$\boxed{\Delta S_{\mathrm{reversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}} = n c_V \ln \left(\frac{T_F}{T_I}\right) = \Delta S_{\mathrm{irreversible}}^{\mathrm{system, \ isochoric}}}.$$

Thus, we could have chosen the same reversible pathway to evaluate the entropy change in isothermal, isochoric and isobaric transformations.
So, why is it that in some transformations (isothermal, isobaric, isochoric) the entropy variation for a closed system is the same in the reversible and irreversible case, and in others (adiabatic) it is not?
(Small edit) Related to this, is there a (possibly detailed) physical (or Physics-related) explanation for each of the transformations (isothermal, isobaric, isochoric, adiabatic)?

In the three cases where you got the same entropy change for the reversible and irreversible processes you characterized your initial and final states by two parameters, the temperature and the volume. The P-V systems, however, only has two degrees of freedom, so once you require two states to have the same temperature and volume, you have required that they be then same state. So in these three cases you have calculated the entropy change between two states via two different methods and found you got the same answer, as you should.
In the reversible adiabatic case, however, you did not actually characterize the final state fully, you merely observed that it must be somewhere on a curve of constant entropy. If you then specified, say, a final volume this would then allow you calculate the final temperature, which would not necessarily be the the $T_F$ in your formula for the irreversible entropy change.
The problem here is really that to make a fair comparison you needed a way to specify the end points of the processes that followed naturally from the processes themselves, but irreversible processes can be more or less anything. There are many possible irriversible isothermal processes and no particular reason to single one out to compare with the reversible case. The only natural way to pair them with the 'corresponding' reversible processes is by fully matching the end points, which obviously leads to trial equivalences.

Thanks. However, I had also asked for a more or less detailed explanation of why the entropy change is the same for a reversible isochore and an irreversible isochore; for a reversible isobar and an irreversible isobar; for a reversible isotherm and an irreversible isotherm. For each of these processes. Can you edit your answer to that effect?

My first paragraph addressed these three cases. The reasoning is identical in each case, so I see no reason to address them individually. Is there anything that is not clear

You talked about endpoints, but I would like a more physics-related answer (e.g. why does the entropy stays in the system in a specific process?) The following paragraph is not so clear: "In the reversible adiabatic case, however, you did not actually characterize the final state fully, you merely observed that it must be somewhere on a curve of constant entropy. If you then specified, say, a final volume this would then allow you calculate the final temperature, which would not necessarily be the the $T_F$ in your formula for the irreversible entropy change". What are you trying to say here?

Lets try this from a different angle. The question you seem to want to ask "How does an reversible process compare to an 'equivalent' irreversible one". The problem here is that there isn't a single equivalent irreversible process, there are many, so you choose which one you are talking about. The way you have chosen to do this is to specify the endpoints of the process, but this a) still does not actually fully specify the process. We still don't know what happened along the way, so I can't give you a "more physical" picture. And b) fixes the final result to be the same as the reversible case

This means the result for getting the same entropy is not very physically meaningful to the question to the question you started with. It is just the result of an arbitrary choice you made along the way without realizing

You are of course right, but it remains obscure to me why in a reversible adiabatic process the entropy change of the system is always zero, while in a corresponding irreversible adiabatic process (assuming there are infinite ones) there is not one that returns a $0$ change, and indeed we have seen that it does not. You probably wrote this in your answer, but I cannot understand or catch it even on further reading. I would be grateful if you could clarify this.

As @Chet Miller already pointed out in his answer, a reversible adiabatic process and an irreversible adiabatic process cannot connect the same two equilibrium states.  The reason for this is as follows:
There are two ways in which the entropy of a system can change, entropy that is transferred between the system and the surroundings and entropy that is generated within the system due to an irreversible transformation. The transfer of entropy between the system and surroundings can only occur in the form of heat. Since heat is zero for an adiabatic process, there can be no change in system entropy due to entropy transfer.
Thus the only way system entropy can change in an adiabatic system is if it is generated within the system due to the process being irreversible. In order for the irreversible adiabatic process to have no change in entropy between the initial and final states like the reversible process, the system must somehow get rid of the entropy generated by the irreversible process, by transferring it to the surroundings in the form of heat.  But since heat is not possible in an adiabatic process, the entropy generated in the system  is effectively "trapped" in the system, meaning the change in entropy of the irreversible and reversible adiabatic processes cannot be the same.
Bottom line: Since the change in entropy of the system between equilibrium states must be the same for all paths between the states,  a reversible and irreversible adiabatic process cannot connect the same two equilibrium states.
Hope this helps.

To get the change in entropy for an irreversible process, we must devise a reversible path between the same two end states as for the irreversible process.  However, the reversible path does not have to bear any resemblance whatsoever to the irreversible process as long as it joins the same two end states.  In the case of an adiabatic irreversible process, for example, there is no adiabatic reversible path between the same two end state.
ADDENDUM
You can't have an adiabatic reversible path between the same two end states as for an irreversible adiabatic path because the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible path is positive and the entropy change for an adiabatic reversible path is zero.  So the final states can't be the same.
The entropy change for a reversible isochore and an irreversible isochore are the same because the initial and final states are the same. The same goes for reversible and irreversible isothermal paths (as long as the final temperatures and volumes are the same).
Irreversible and reversible isobaric processes do not go between the same initial and final states for adiabatic isobaric processes.

Thanks. However, what is the difference between "devise" and "ideate"? Also, why isn't there any "adiabatic reversible path between the same two end state"?. Also, I had asked for a more or less detailed explanation of why the entropy change is the same for a reversible isochore and an irreversible isochore; for a reversible isobar and an irreversible isobar; for a reversible isotherm and an irreversible isotherm. For each of these processes. Can you edit your answer to that effect?

See the Addendum.

Thanks. I have two doubts: 1) "You can't have an adiabatic reversible path between the same two ed states as for an irreversible adiabatic path because the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible path is positive and the entropy change for an adiabatic reversible path is zero. So the final states can't be the same.": I don't get it. Why does the fact that "the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible path is positive and the entropy change for an adiabatic reversible path is zero" imply that "the final states can't be the same"?


"Irreversible and reversible isobaric processes does not go between the same initial and final state for adiabatic isobaric processes.": sorry, I don't understand what you mean here at all. Can you reformulate?


To get a better understanding of how to determine the entropy changes in irreversible processes, including worked examples, see this link:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/

Thanks, I already knew this link: it is famous because it is given in many Thermodynamics answers on Physics SE. I find it to be an excellent recipe. My doubts, however, are a little different: what does it mean that "Irreversible and reversible isobaric processes does not go between the same initial and final state for adiabatic isobaric processes"? I just don't understand, what is different about isobaric processes versus isochoric or isothermal processes? Also, could you clarify my doubt 1) about adiabatic processes? Many thanks.

It mans the for an adiabatic irreversible process, there is no adiabatic reversible path between the same two end states.  It is impossible to devise such a reversible path.  To get reversibly between the initial and final end states, you will need to exchange heat with the surroundings.

OK, I got it. But what about my doubt 2)? "Irreversible and reversible isobaric processes does not go between the same initial and final state for adiabatic isobaric processes": what does that mean? What is different about isobaric processes versus isochoric or isothermal processes?

in an  irreversible "isobaric" process, the pressure is changed suddenly at the starting state, and then the process is allowed to proceed at the new (constant) pressure for the remainder of the process.  So, even though it seems like the pressure is constant throughout the process, it is not.

OK, thanks. So 1) I think "adiabatic isobaric processes" is a typo, isn't? 2) Since "irreversible and reversible isobaric processes do not go between the same initial and final state", why is the change in entropy for a closed system the same for isobaric processes, as I have shown in my question?

Even though the formulas are the same, the parameter values you plug in for the final state are not.

The last point is interesting, but I cannot fully understand it. May I ask another follow-up question to analyze the entropy change (system and environment) for each of the transformations?

Why don’t you start a new thread with a specific focus problem?
